# Responsive Design / What is an appropriate web component to choose a distance regarding user's geolocation?

Tags: usability, mobile, web-app, responsive-design, user-expectation

I own a responsive web application.

I want to let user filter results (supposing a page listing some data) based on his geolocation and a chosen limit.

For instance, **Bob wants to see all meetings that are within 10km only**.

What would be an appropriate component, especially on mobile device?

I found [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html) (the first item), but it could be touchy to represent a large slider on narrow mobile device, and not easy to be accurate for people having large fingers.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a numeric stepper. The user may enter the value with the keyboard, or use the up/down arrows. The default value should be empty (no distance filter).

EDIT : See comment by @FodderZone

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs8xw9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I thought about that, nice to have a confirmation :) Thanks :)

Comment: But with this solution, how to let the user query results without filtering by distance? What would be a way for the user to disable this filter no matter how kilometers are set?

Comment: With a slider as suggested, we may have a bound labeled with "Everywhere", representing any distance.

Comment: When the field is empty the distance filter is disabled. The user can delete the field value any time. The default value will be empty.

Comment: Isn't an associated checkbox labeled as "Within X km" relevant? When checked, the numeric stepper appeared and when unchecked, it is hidden. I doubt that many lambda users will try to empty the field in order to bypass the filter. It sounds too implicit.

Comment: It depends from how much experience your users have with filters. If they have some basic experience, in my opinion you do not need to add any addtional elements. But if your users are novice, you need additional elements to make it clear, like the checkbox or a label next to the numeric stepper "Within any distance" displayed ONLY when the the field is empty.

Comment: Understood :) Actually, targeted users are .. everybody since the app will be public.

Comment: Do your users care about the difference between 10 KM and 11 KM? If not, I would suggest a drop down list of options like "1 KM", "5 KM", "10 KM", "25 KM". My experience is that counter fields like you show above are less intuitive.

Comment: No they don't care about such precision. Yes, why not a drop down list like you suggested with "Everywhere" by default. The label would be simply: "Meeting distance"

Comment: This is going to be a bit fiddly to use with your fingers on a small mobile screen, no?

Answer (score 2):

I think a slider that has stepped values should work reasonably well on a mobile device too, especially if you don't have to be very precise with the distance. The end points can be a minimum distance, and the maximal value can be everywhere.